# Objective-C - Google Maps 1.8.1 - iOS 7.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-maps

I had already added the framework in my project. Everything was working perfectly fine.
When I updated the framework happens the following exception:

```
'-[GMSCachedTile setPerTileExpiration:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1933d3a0'
```

Tried to return to the previous version, but the same thing keeps happening.

*PS: ITried Clean and build, but without success.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we add the Google Maps framework to our project it creates a reference to framework automatically in Build Settings on Framework search paths. When we exclude the framework he does not remove automatically this reference.

Turns out I came across references the old version of the framework that was using. I removed this reference and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Remove (Move to trash dont remove reference only) old SDK, download and drag latest one. 
Run clean and It is done.